# How to change color loader with minimal player style in YouTubePlayer?

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

YouTubePlayerSupportFragment has a minimal style. loader color is green. You need to change the color of the loader to another
[current loader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNeiZ.png)

I created a player

```
private var player: YouTubePlayer? = null
var fragment: YouTubePlayerSupportFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance()
```

and initialized it. 
Where set the minimal style of the player

```
fragment.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, object : YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
            override fun onInitializationSuccess(p0: YouTubePlayer.Provider?, p1: YouTubePlayer?, p2: Boolean) {
                player = p1
                player?.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.MINIMAL)
                if (!p2) {
                    player?.cueVideo(getIdVideo(uri))
                }
            }

            override fun onInitializationFailure(p0: YouTubePlayer.Provider?, p1: YouTubeInitializationResult?) {

            }
        })
```

As a result, the video is loaded with a green progressBar.
Styles accent color is red

I looked in the YouTube documentation and did not find anything there that could help me.

Comment: What is the problem? Clarify please

Comment: Sorry if I asked the wrong question. Need to make the loader red

Comment: This forum is not like "make it for me" its about "i did this and this but something wrong please help me figure out what happened." So try to write code and we will help you

Comment: Sorry. I fixed the question

Comment: What loader do you mean? The progress lane?

Comment: No, I need to change the color of the current

Comment: I recommend using exoplayer check my answer below :)

Comment: Does exoplayer support playing videos from YouTube?

Comment: thank you for edit your question. Changed my devote because now its more clear. Next time please provide all details

Answer (score 1):

All visual modification you could do with help of `YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle But it is not so flexible as you want I guess and you could just choose some default styles like here

https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle

One more variant which is VERY flexible to play videos is ExoPlayer which i prefer better and here is an example. CHECK THIS LINK BELOW. Even Udacity and google forums recommend it

https://medium.com/fungjai/playing-video-by-exoplayer-b97903be0b33

Easy to customize it
[image]

[image]

[image]